# Is there a word that means the trait asking a question out of skepticism in hopes of finding the truth?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

There are many synonyms for asking a question. Is there one that means or implies that the person asking the question is skeptical and hopes to find the truth? It'd have to be in the form of a trait. For instance, *integrity, honesty*, etc. The closest I could think of is *investigable*.

Comment: You need to expand on this. I am thinking 'playing the devil's advocate' may be what you want. But I need to understand more clearly the meaning you have in mind.

Comment: What is an example of a question demonstrating this trait?  Does something very simple like `Bob doesn't really have two heads, does he?` qualify?

Comment: Socratic method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that person is a "skeptic" and being "skeptical".

Comment: And the trait would be skepticism.

Comment: This answer seems to be the closest. The sentence in question uses the word as a noun. "He was a man of integrity, honesty, and skepticism". I appreciate the feedback! There were many good suggestions. I found the suggestion of "Socractic dialogue" particularly interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a verb form for this, but if I've understood your question correctly, you could describe the act of asking with the adverb *dubiously*.

Example:

> "Are you sure that giant slice of cake is good for you?" he asked dubiously.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Socratic dialogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_dialogue), in which a character (Socrates in the works by Plato) leads a companion to greater understanding by asking a series of seemingly trivial questions, that slowly build up to an argument of a contrary position to that originally postulated by the companion.